# fs.readFileSync() no callback and encode doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, fs

I wrote this little test code in an attempt to debug another project of mine and discovered that fs.readFileSync() appears to have no callback function and encoding doesn't work.

```
const fs = require("fs");

var x = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/file.txt", {encode: "utf8"}, () => {

    console.log("Callback function?");

});

console.log(x);
```

Expected output:
"Callback function?"
*content of file.txt*

But I simply recieved ""

What is wrong here?

Comment: Sync functions don't use callbacks as they're synchronous. And the property is `encoding`, not `encode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). It clearly shows no callback, and I guess the call doesn't work because you gave a function instead of the "flags" option and it kinda messed it up.

Also, this is called "readFile**SYNC**" - Synchronous actions by default does not have a callback, you can just write what you want to happen right after them- and it will happen right after them. No timing issues because again- they are synchronous.

The right code for your program would be:

`var x = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/file.txt", { encoding: "utf8" });`, and after this log w/e you want or do with data w/e you want, it will be inside X variable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure either you want synchronous operations in Node.js or asynchronous, but I see you are using synchronous function fs.readFileSync, and trying to access via async approach

For reading a file you can use the readFileSync method of the fs class: like

```
  const fs = require("fs");
    const output = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/file.txt");
    console.log(output);
```

For getting data asynchronously, you will get content in call back.

```
fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) doesn't take a callback, since it runs synchronously. It will return the file data.

If you do wish to read a file asynchronously, use [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).

Here's an example of both:

```
// Sync. readFile
const fileData = fs.readFileSync("some_file.txt", { encoding: "utf8"});
console.log("fileData:", fileData);

// Async. readFile
fs.readFile("some_file.txt", { encoding: "utf8"}, (err, fileData) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", err);
    } else {
        console.log("fileData:", fileData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok so, callback is only for async functions. However, I still have the issue of not being able to encode to utf-8.

Comment: Are you setting the options to {encoding: "utf8"} ? In your code it is set to {encode: "utf8" }, this won't work! You could also just use a string set to "utf8", for example: fs.readFileSync("file.txt", "utf8"). Hope this helps!